# Angular 4 access DB model

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, angular

I'm currently learning Angular 4 and I have a task to create an organization chart visualization. I found multiple options how to do it and I picked this [one](http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2016/07/google-organization-chart-using-angularjs.html).
I chose it because it utilizes SQL database which I'm also supposed to use. The only problem for me is since the project is written in AngularJS that I have to migrate it to Angular 4 and I'm failing to come up with the proper way to do it.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, empty ASP.NET web application project with MVC folder layout and this is what I have done so far:

1. Usual Angular setup (*npm install, AppModule bootstrap...*)
2. I have a database running and I created an ADO model.
3. I have a **HomeController.cs** in Controllers folder.

**HomeController.cs**

```
using Pas.Angular.OrgChart.Models;

namespace Pas.Angular.OrgChart.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult GetEmployees()
        {
            List<Employees> emp = new List<Employees>();
            using (EmployeesDBEntities dc = new EmployeesDBEntities())
            {
                emp = dc.Employees.OrderBy(a => a.PositionID).ToList();
            }
            return new JsonResult
            {
                Data = emp,
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
        }
    }
}
```

3. I have an **employees.service.ts** in which I'm trying to get a JSON object full of employees.

**employees.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Headers, Http } from "@angular/http";

import "rxjs/add/operator/toPromise";

@Injectable()
export class EmployeesService {
    private headers: Headers;
    private baseUrl = "/Home/GetEmployees" // Question no. 1


    constructor(private http: Http) {
       // Question no. 2
    }

    getEmployees(): Promise<JSON[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl) // Question no. 2
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.log("An error has occurred: ", error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
namespace Pas.Angular.OrgChart
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

4. My folder structure looks like this

[image: Folders structure]

Additional info:

1. EmployeesService is registered as a provider in AppModule
2. EmployeesComponent calls service method *getEmployees()* on init.
3. This code is just a POC, all I want to do is log a JSON output.
4. The only output for me so far is: `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: http://localhost:3002/Home/GetEmployees`

**My questions are** (*referring to numbers in code*):

1. How can I check that this URL is correct and if not to what url should I change it to?
2. Do I need headers? I saw some ways how to initialize them but it's just
   not making any sense for me.
3. Is there something else I'm missing and I'm not aware of it?

Last notes:

Using the tutorial from the link on the top I was able to make it run so I guess that my DB and DB model are OK. If you think this question lacks some important info let me know in comments and I'll add it. As I mentioned before, I'm new to Angular and I might be overlooking some important stuff.

Comment: Can you also include the `RouteConfig` here?

Comment: Added RouteConfig.cs

Answer (score 2):

You should take closer look at attribute routing and also how to create a proper REST-ful API. The **Employee** entity should have its own controller, instead of being nested in the Home-controller.

The problem that you're facing right now is due to the route *GetEmployees* not being available, as there is already a default GET method defined on your HomeController (The *Index()* method).

Add a new **EmployeesController** in the **Controllers** folder, and put the **GetEmployees** method in there.
In that way, you would be able to get all employees in a REST-ful way using a call like *http://localhost:3002/Employees* to get all employees, which also resonates much better with the way that Angular 2 services are supposed to be built. (I'm guessing that you mean Angular 2 and not **4**, right?)

Comment: Thank you for this point, I'll move the logic to the dedicated controller. But actually it is accessible I managed to get it working. See my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found out I had problems with correct URL. Because of some customization I've done in **Index.cshtml** I managed to break it somehow and instead of `http://localhost/OrgChart/Home/GetEmployees` I was using different links which were all incorrect. This is the workaround I came up with.

**employees.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from "@angular/core"; //In order to inject DOCUMENT
import { Headers, Http } from "@angular/http";
import { DOCUMENT } from "@angular/platform-browser";

import "rxjs/add/operator/toPromise";

@Injectable()
export class EmployeesService {
    private empUrl = "Home/GetEmployees";
    private baseUrl: string;

    constructor(private http: Http, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) {
        // document injection and the way how to get the base URL
        this.baseUrl = this.document.location.href + this.empUrl;
        console.log(this.baseUrl);
        // This will create a correct URL
        // http://localhost/OrgChart/Home/GetEmployees
    }

    getEmployees(): Promise<any> {
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.log("An error has occurred: ", error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

This is how **Index.cshtml** head looks like. Without the `href="~/src/"` I'm not able to access script but also because of it the URL ends up being malfunctioned. Hence the workaround.

**Index.cshtml**

```
<head>
    <title>PAS org chart</title>
    <base href="~/src/">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style> ... </style>
    <script src="~/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="~/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('main.js').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
    </script>
</head>
```

I'm not hundred percent sure that I'm doing the right thing but so far it works form me. I'll be glad if you find some risks or mistakes in this workaround and point them out.